# Android video record libraries

Tags: android, video

everyone! I have a question. I need some video recorder (library project) which offer the possibility to set programmatically the maximum output file size and resolution of recording video. I know that native android video recorder allows to set max output file size, but it allows to set only two type of quality(best and worst). I need at least three different video resolutions. So maybe someone know  library which can help me to solve my problem?

Also good to have:
    -zoom;
    -autofocus;
    -flash;

Thanks!

Comment: Hai, You have got any libraries?

Comment: Did you compare all libraries and any suggestion for best library having feature "Best Quality, Zoom, AutoFocus, Flash, Distance detection, Lightning etc"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best libraries which I found:

- CWAC-Camera library (https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera);
- OpenCamera (http://opencamera.sourceforge.net/). But Open Camera is released under the GPL v3. The source code is available from https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencamera/files/.

Comment: Thats nice, Let me look at it. Do you have apk for this library? Any link to download?

Comment: No, sorry, I have not. Earlier I downloaded source code and build projects with Eclipse. For example CWAC lib has demo project (https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/tree/master/demo).

Comment: And open camera apk, seems like there is link for download (http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencamera/files/v_1_20/OpenCamera.apk/download)

Comment: Open camera is open source and licenced?

Answer (score 3):

To anyone reading this recently, CWAC-Camera mentioned on accepted answer is discontinued, then the author re-attempted for a better version, which is found [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2). And the demo is [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/tree/master/demo).

I also found [Material Camera](https://github.com/afollestad/material-camera) that is under the Apache License v2.0. [Here](https://github.com/afollestad/material-camera/tree/master/sample) is the sample project.

There is also [ragnraok/RxCamera](https://github.com/ragnraok/RxCamera), based on [android.hardware.camera](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) although it is said to be still in very early stage, plus the android reference link says [android.hardware.camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) is the recommended API now.

Answer (score 1):

**The best libraries which I found**:
[FFmpegVideoRecorder](https://github.com/amosyuen/FFmpegVideoRecorder) 
The library provides a way to record multiple videos using MediaRecorder and merge them together using FFmpeg Recorder from JavaCV. It is designed to allow maximum customization of the video encoding and recording.

It has built in activities for easy recording and previewing. But it also exposes basic components that can be used to customize your own UI and logic.

**General Features**
Able to record multiple clips and combine them into one video
Camera preview image is scaled, cropped, and padded to exactly how it will be recorded
Can generate a thumbnail image for the video
Can set recording parameters such as:

1. video codec
2. List item
3. video width
4. video height
5. List item
6. video frame
   ....etc

Comment: This library is not working. Followed steps from GitHub. Getting this error: FFmpegRecorderActivity: Error opening camera
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference. Is ffmpeg video recorder working fine for you?

Comment: @Arjun you are Access the Camera multiple time you will access the camera in FFmpagRecoderActivity one time then this Error will be remove . yes its working fine.

Comment: Thank you @zeshan for replying. I didn't access the camera multiple times. I've posted the code I've used here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652268/ffmpeg-video-recorder-issue Could you please have a look at the code. I tried but getting the same error again. When I click on show error info from Logs it opens files in libraries and shows error in them. I'm unable to understand where the code is going wrong. I would really be grateful if you could help me with this. If possible could you share the snippet of how you're recording the video else visit the link mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

To anyone reading this recently,
The author mentioned he plans to DISCONTINUE the project cwac-cam2.. 
Here:
https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/issues/336